# Populate comboboxes from a sheet and fill out userform accordingly?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

So here is the first, working  userform I made for this sheet:[Add_Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kZkr.jpg)

I'm trying to make a second userform to edit records created with this first one. In appearance it is near identical except the "Business name" text box (Textbox1) is replaced with Combobox5.

Combobox4, the employee combobox is populated from a second sheet in the workbook called "Employees". I think this might be the root of my problem.

The code for the combo boxes for the Add_Form is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem ""
        .AddItem "Weekly"
        .AddItem "Biweekly"
        .AddItem "Monthly"
        .AddItem "As Needed"
        
    End With
    
    
    With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        .AddItem ""
        .AddItem "Check"
        .AddItem "Debit/Credit Card"
        .AddItem "Direct Deposit"
        .AddItem "Other"
        
    End With
    
    
    
    With Me.ComboBox3
        .Clear
        .AddItem ""
        .AddItem "Weekly"
        .AddItem "Biweekly"
        .AddItem "Monthly"
        .AddItem "As Needed"
        
    End With
    
    
    
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Me.ComboBox4.Clear
    Me.ComboBox4.AddItem ""
    
    For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox4.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    Next i
    
    

End Sub
```

What I would like to happen with this Edit_Form is Combobox5 to populate from the A column of the first sheet, "Customers", and then ideally fill in the rest of the form according to the selected business. I tried

```
    
  


    
    Me.ComboBox5.Clear
    Me.ComboBox5.AddItem ""
    
    For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox5.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    Next i
```

And

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheets("Employees").Range("A")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Customers").Range("A")


Dim i as Integer 
    
    Me.ComboBox4.Clear
    Me.ComboBox4.AddItem ""
    
    For i = 2 To sh.rng1("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox4.AddItem sh.rng1("A" & i).Value

    
    Me.ComboBox5.Clear
    Me.ComboBox5.AddItem ""
    
    For i = 2 To sh.rng2("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox5.AddItem sh.rng2("A" & i).Value
    Next i
```

But I can't even get Combobox5 to populate. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Application` doesn't have a `Rows` property. Chane all `Application.Rows.Count` to `sh.Rows.Count` (or whatever Worksheet variable you're using at the time)

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is missing a `Next i` in the first for loop. But the attempt before that seems to work for me. Both the following subroutines, when added to `UserForm_Initialize`, populated the combobox as expected.

My Attempt from scratch:

```
Public Sub PopulateComboBox()

    Me.cbBusinessName.AddItem "<select>"
    
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Companies")
    Set namesRng = Intersect(WS.Columns(1), WS.UsedRange)
    
    For Each companyName In namesRng
        Me.cbBusinessName.AddItem companyName.Value
    Next companyName

End Sub
```

Based on your first attempt:

```
Public Sub PopulateComboBox()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Companies")

    Me.cbBusinessName.Clear
    Me.cbBusinessName.AddItem ""
    
    For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.cbBusinessName.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

P.S. It's a really good practice to rename controls with a descriptive name as soon as they're added to the form. This helps you keep track in the code.

P.P.S. We can't see where you defined `sh` for your edit form. This could be another place to look for your issue. Maybe you are not pointing to the sheet you are intending to.

Answer (score 0):

@BoilermakerRV thank you for the help. I ended up having to rebuild from scratch but took your advice and renamed all controls to keep me organized.

For those interested, heres the code:

```
     Dim sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")
   
   Dim i As Integer
   
   Me.EmpCombo.Clear
   Me.EmpCombo.AddItem ""
   
   For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Me.EmpCombo.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value
   Next i

   
  
   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customers")
   
   
   Me.BusCombo.Clear
   Me.BusCombo.AddItem ""
   
   For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Me.BusCombo.AddItem sh.Range("A" & i).Value
   Next I
```